# BGI error: Graphics not initialized ( use "initgraph")

Tags: path, bgi

my bgi path is C:\TURBOC3\BGI but it is not working.i already tried the suggestion

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There should be 2 slashes along the path. Like this-

```
"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI"
```